# Doctype meta and quirksmode

Tags: html, xhtml, doctype, quirks-mode

Please can I clarify some thinking here:

Quirksmode is invoked if no doctype is specified.

but

When served from localhost IE appears to go into quirksmode regardless of doctype. Please can this be confirmed and can someone explain why this is the case.

however

When served from localhost and IE goes into quirksmode regardless of doctype this can be overridden by including a meta tag in the first line of the head

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

This doesn't work for me ... have I got the syntax wrong?

The meta in the head will only ever be applied when served from localhost? Is this true if so why.

At the moment everything looks fine in FF Chrome Opera etc whether served from localhost or across the net.

But I just get quirks mode in IE

My doctype is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Finally is there a relationship between charset and quirksmode?

I have been using

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

On apache with apache config set to default to UTF-8

Comment: How did you check if it was running quirks mode? have you [validated](http://validator.w3.org/) your XHTML? That is absolutely necessary with XHTML.

Comment: You also specify that your content = text/html, [W3 states that this is not appropriate for XHTML documents](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/)

Comment: Ah ok. I used IE's developer tools which show mode to be quirksmode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to summarise the findings from this question.

To switch off compatibility mode in IE9

1. in IE 9 right click tools icon and select command bar
2. from command bar select tools
3. from tools select Compatibility View Settings
4. uncheck display intranet site in compatibility mode
5. from command bar select tools ensure compatibility view is unchecked
6. Restart Browser

Main points for changing code

- The html 5 doctype simplifies the whole issue of setting a doctype.
- The reason that there appeared to be a relationship between charset and quirksmode was the error in the meta to add that charset which put it in conflict with the doctype.

So actions completed to resolve problem.

1. Ignore localhost quirksmode - this is only significant when testing.
2. Use `<!Doctype html>` ensuring that the html document commences with this. N:B this does not mean that this has to be the first line of the HTML. php includes can precede it.
3. In the `<head>` Use `<meta charset="UTF-8">`
4. In php initialize use `<?php header("content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

[Quirks Mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html) is quirky, and you should not rely on anything particular regarding it. The situations where it is triggered are browser-dependent, but if you have seen an XHTML doctype, conforming to XHTML specs, to trigger it, then it’s probably a mistake in observations. You might have e.g. some stuff before the doctype. Ditto for the magic `meta` tag regarding IE.

You may have the syntax wrong, but not in the snippets posted.

Or the issue could be caused by some of the [IE8 and IE9 complications](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/#ie8) in doctype sniffing.

There is no relationship between charset and Quirks Mode.

Comment: Ok I do get confused here. Not everything can be the first line of code. I use redirection with buffering so my php initialization include can be other than in the first line. Can I confirm that you are saying the doctype should be ahead of any includes? ditto meta's

Comment: @codepuppy, no, PHP directives are internal to the server. They are not sent to browsers, so they do not affect a browser’s choice of mode, except indirectly if the directive generates some content into the document.

Comment: @codepuppy, if your file starts with a PHP directive and you open the file locally from a file, then the directive will appear in the document as the browser sees it, and will mess things up. If you meant that you open it from an http server running locally in your system (http://localhost/...), then perhaps that server is different from the web server (perhaps has PHP disabled?).

Comment: I meant the latter. Both servers are apache. PHP is enabled on both.

Comment: @codepuppy, perhaps the servers still behave differently; use View Source in a browser to see if there is a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Two things, you can try IE=8 etc....

You may also want to check doctype; although, it looks correct you might have hidden characters etc.... try using a basic editor that will show hidden characters.

For VI you can look at: http://www.chrispian.com/quick-vi-tip-show-hidden-characters/.

This would be a first step for me.

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Is where it goes wrong, because you say it's `text/html` while your doctype is xhtml. You should use `application/xhtml+xml`.

### Longer answer

It seems to me that you have not properly researched what **XHTML actually is**. This is a very strange kind of document. XHTML was supposed to be an improvement on traditional HTML but it never really got popular and generally it's not recommend that you use it **unless you have very specific reasons**.

Have a look at [this web site](http://www.greytower.net/archive/articles/xhtmlcontent.html). Some important sections:

> XHTML 1.1
>
> For the 1.1 version of XHTML the specifications are clear: text/html
>   MAY NOT be used. The XHTML "native" content type of
>   application/xhtml+xml SHOULD be used, whilst the generic XML content
>   type of application/xml MAY be used.
>
> This soup of content types leaves us with a fairly clear course of
>    action for 1.1: if we use XHTML 1.1 2, we should serve
>    application/xhtml+xml as the content type.

And here's your problem specifically:

> The horror! The Horror!
>
> You've guessed it. Serving up a document containing what is to all
>   intents and purposes XHTML as text/html simply means that **browsers
>   will jump into error correcting mode and deal.**

Comment: This answer is completely wrong – sorry! Comments are too short to explain in detail, but using application/xhtml+xml will break your page in most IEs, and will cause it not to render in other browsers if you have any errors at all. XHTML1.1 essentially isn't supported, and shouldn't be used. XHTML1.0 is pointless for reasons you've touched on. codepuppy should ensure that there are no new lines before the doctype, and ideally use the HTML5 one to minimise the chance of errors.

Comment: Well I would not say that have not researched this because I have but may be my understanding is lacking. My reason for choosing xhtml was to try to ensure that I adhered to the standards. The reason for including the charset meta was to remove the charset error I was getting in FF. I.e. it was demanding UTF-8. So if I understand correctly there is no relationship between the charset and quirksmode other than the syntax I have used conflicts with the doctype causing the browser to default to quirksmode. . @Rich

Comment: I have indeed noted the html 5 doctype I have read several postings on this. What was unclear to me was whether this is backwardly compatible. It would appear that that is answered here .. i.e. that it is. @Rich

Comment: The idea of doctypes is kinda silly when you think about it – why would you ever want quirks mode? The HTML5 doctype was designed to be the shortest code that didn't trigger quirks mode (no doctype = quirks). XHTML ended up being a dead end, partly because IE didn't support it, and partly because it's too easy to break the whole site (any invalid XHTML 1.1 = no site). Use `<meta charset="utf-8" />` for the charset, but also ensure you PHP/Ruby/Python whatever sends a header like `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`. The header is more important for things to work.

Comment: Also, pretty much everything in Mario's answer is irrelevant to you. You weren't trying to use XHTML1.1, just the old 1.0, so pretty much everything isn't relevant to your situation.

Comment: Yes indeed - This blog posting by John Resig sums it up very nicely http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-doctype/#postcomment in particular the following comment : "As I mentioned, it simply puts the document into standards mode. IE6 and IE7 will ignore the new HTML 5 features (along with Firefox, etc.) but at the very least you’ll be able to develop in your existing standards-based way, looking towards the future."   I hope that this helps others struggling with this.

Comment: @Rich to clarify IN ADDITION to <meta charset="utf-8"/> my initialize include should contain <?php header("content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); ?>

Comment: That's one way to do it. Make sure that that happens before anything else. It's probably better if your server (say, Apache) does that for you. In Apache, you'd add `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` to your .htaccess file. This https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.htaccess is a great reference for a top quality server set up btw. (And the whole project contains loads of great resources)