# CSS Table layout: make rows span full width without centering cells

Tags: css, layout

I have a layout as shown in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4dbgnqha/4/. For reasons that you can read about in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500858/clear-float-and-prevent-text-wrap-without-hack) post, I don't want to change the way the page is laid out.

Now, it works fairly well, but the issue is that when I add a border to the bottom of the `.item` divs, I realize that they don't span the full width of the page. As you can see in the above fiddle, the second `.item` down doesn't have enough content to fill the width, so its border doesn't reach the full width.

I thought I could fix this by just adding `.item { width: 100%; }`, but when I do that, the image gets added enough additional width to center the `p`, which looks really weird. Demo of that: https://jsfiddle.net/4dbgnqha/7/

I know it will fix if I add a set width to the image, but as I mentioned in my original post, I want it to be really flexible, able to have many image widths. I also know that if I wrap the image in an element and set that element to a really small width, like `1px`, it will work, but that seems like a hack, and the reason I'm doing this stupid table layout in the first place is that I'm trying to avoid any such hacks.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What's wrong with setting the `.item` width to 100%? I'm not fully understanding that.

Comment: Take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/4dbgnqha/7/. See how the <p> of the second item down is sort of floating in the middle? @Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this into the CSS, it's a hack, but works very well with table layout.

```
.item p {
    width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4dbgnqha/8/

Answer (score 1):

you need to add width 100% to the `.item p` element so it gets the maximum available width, otherwise that element will get `width:auto`. So just add `width:100%` like this:

```
.item p {
    margin: 0px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
}
```

edit: well, now I see it was already answered, but for anyone looking for info, [this is why it happens](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#auto-table-layout)